# Прижатый к низу footer в резиновой вёрстке

Tags: html, css

*Это не дубликат вопроса «[Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/546490/208074)». Там подвал прикрепляется безусловно. Мне же необходимо прикрепление только если страница не помещается по вертикали на экан.*

---

Как сверстать `<footer>`, удовлетворяющих описанный ниже условиям?

1. В соответсвии с принципом резиновой вёрстки, его ширина всегда равна ширине окна (Это условие исключает позиционирование).
2. Если высота окна больше высоты содержимого, то футер прижат к низу окна, образуя пробел с основным содержимым (это смотрится лучше, чем пробел после футера).
3. Если высота окна меньше высоты содержимого, то вертикальный скроллинг оканчивается на футере.

Чтобы съэкономить Ваше время, я сделал простую заготовку на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/md3f0yyf/).

```
<header></header>
<main>Если ничего не ввести, то не отображается даже при заданной высоте. </main>
<footer></footer>

header{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #F5A9A9;
}

main{
  //display: block; // Кроссбраузерность для IE
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #F5F6CE;
}

footer{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #E0F8E6;
}
```

Comment: выглядит ка ТЗ.

Comment: 2006 год http://lynn.ru/examples/footer-at-bottom.xhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**cамый простой способ, без js**

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body{
    height:100%;
    min-height:;
}
header,footer{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:120px;
    background: lightgreen;
    padding:10px 20px;
}

.wrapper{
    min-height:100%;
    position: relative;
    background:#eee;
}
.content{
    padding-bottom:120px;
}
.content p{
    display:block;
    width:80%;
    margin:30px auto;
    background: #ddeedd;
    padding:20px;
    text-align: justify;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> 
<header>
  <h3>header</h3>
</header>
<div class="content"></div>
<footer>
  <p>Copyright 2016 </p>
</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: demo : https://jsfiddle.net/atlanta/md3f0yyf/1/

Comment: Благодарю Вас за решение! Похоже, я не совсем корректро сказал про позиционирование в вопросе: резиновый эффект длины 100% отменяет только горизонтальное позиционирование, так?

Comment: вообще можно абсолютно всё разместить так как требуется по замыслу , главное понять что требуется , для расширения html был придуман js_framework  -- angular , и с этим дополнением вообще можно сделать всё _ ВСЁ

Comment: Как Вы знаете, в профессиональной вёрстке важно не только точное соответствие дезайну, но и достижение этого соотсветствия минимальными средствами и максимально упрощённой разметкой. Средств действительно много, но их использование наверняка "бесплатно" не даётся (снижение скорости загрузки, проблемы с кроссбраузерностью и т. д.).

Comment: Gurebu Bokofu Это вы кому сказали ?

Comment: Вам, но с расчётом на то, что это прочтут другие новички, так то, что я сказил, Вы знаете.

Comment: вы не попутали ? кто новичёк то ? лесом шли бы - сенсей , проверьте это в любом браузере и мобильном устройстве

Comment: Вы меня не правильно поняли. Когда я говорил "другие новички", под новичком из нас двоих имел ввиду себя, а не Вас.

Comment: Gurebu Bokofu  извени

Comment: Ещё раз благодарю Вас за решении моей задачи. Удачного дня! ^_^