# Table-элементы: занять оставшееся место по высоте

Tags: html, css

Задача:

- **Горизонтальное поведение**: как на картинке ниже; левая колонка занимает фиксированную ширину, остальные две делят по 50% оставшейся ширины, но имеют `min-width`.
- **Вертикальное поведение**: колонки имеют одинаковую высоту, достигающую футера, а сам футер находится в нижней части экрана, когда высота окна больше высоты содержимого, или идёт сразу после контента, когда меньше (данная задача была решена [в этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545000/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83-footer-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5) вопросе).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для обеспечения требуемого горизонтального поведения лучше всего подходят свойства `display:table;`, `display:table:cell;`, с этими средствами сделать нужное горизонтальное поведение не составляет труда.

Но что с вертикальным? По своей природе, таблица должна иметь высоту, равную сумме высот строк, и если мы вмешивается в управление высотой таблицы, произойдёт растяжение строк, чего не требовалось (я показал на картинке, что контент собран в верхней части ячеек).

Получается прямо-таки конфликт между требованиями к горизонтальному и вертикальному поведению. Есть ли какие-нибудь средства, которые позволяют обеспечить оба поведения?

P. S. Хочу `wrap-content` и `match-parent` из XML-вёрстки под android...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял, то вот решение. Футер к низу прижимается, колонки одинаковой высоты, одна из них фиксирована по ширине, остальные делят оставшееся пространство поровну.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}
.container__columns {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  background: #5d8cf7;
}

.column1 {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.column2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #f75d5d;
  padding: 20px;
}

.column3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #66f75d;
  padding: 20px;
}
.pagefooter {  
  padding: 20px;
  background: #d85df7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__columns">
    <div class="column1">1</div>
    <div class="column2">2</div>
    <div class="column3">3</div>
  </div>
  <footer class="pagefooter">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за потраченное время на решения задачи! Конкретно в моём случае лучше подходит flexbox, потому поставлю галочку этому решению.

Comment: Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой в Вашем решении; решил вынести обсуждение в [отдельный вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600901/flexbox-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-50-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE).

Answer (score 1):

Вариант, если нужно использовать `display: table-cell`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.pagefooter {
  height: 40px;
  background: #f75d88;
  padding: 5px;
}

.columns {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.column1,
.column2,
.column3 {
  padding: 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
}

.column1 {
  width: 150px;
  background: #fff8a5;
}

.column2,
.column3 {
  width: calc(50% - 150px);
  background: #5db0f7;
}

.column3 {
  background: #5df7a2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column1">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="column3">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="pagefooter">footer</footer>
</div>
```